# fade in lightbox with css transitions

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make this lightbox fade in and out, would ideally like to do it with CSS if possible. Any suggestions?

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/UhV3M/)

**HTML**

```
<section id="about">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <button id="hide" class="close">close</button>
            <h1>About</h1>
    </div>
</section>
<a id="show" href="#about" class="scroll">About</a>
```

**JS**

```
// Simple show and hide button
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#about").hide();
});
$("#show").click(function(){
    $("#about").show();
});
```

Comment: Use transition :opacity property to animate without jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut` instead of `.show` and `.hide`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, I would recommend using CSS3 transitions instead of jQuery's [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) functions, since they perform poorly on most mobile devices. I would recommend using a plugin such as [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) which works along side jQuery that allows for smooth animations:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hide").click(function () {
        $("#about").transition({opacity: 0 }, function () { $(this).hide(); });
    });
    $("#show").click(function () {
        $("#about").show().transition({opacity: 1 });
    });
});
```

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ArtVa/)